# tkinter: how to make Radiobuttons with loop that wont select every button when one is selected?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter and am trying to make a program where you can select, for each radio button, any of the two values. every time I run the code, I end up selecting every radio button of that group, ie if I select one radio button from string, every button gets selected. I want the program to run in such a way that I can select a distinct option for each line. What am I doing wrong?

my code is:

```
import tkinter as tk
str_int_lst = list()

class Creation(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.master = master

        self.master.title('Creation')
        self.frame_test()

    def frame_test(self):

        data_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='Gold', height=122, width=200)

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=5)
        for i in range(1, 13):
            self.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

        data_frame.grid(row=2, rowspan=10, sticky='W' + 'E' + 'N' + 'S')


        entry = list()
        check_radio = tk.StringVar()
        for j in range(10):
            global lst

            tk.Label(data_frame, text=f'enter key {j + 1}', bg='Gold', font=('Times New Roman', 10)).grid(row=2 + j,
                                                                                                          padx=(50, 0))
            entry.append(tk.Entry(data_frame))
            entry[j].grid(row=2 + j, column=1, padx=(10, 10))

            radio_int = tk.Radiobutton(data_frame, text='Integer', variable=check_radio, value=1,
                                       command=str_int_lst.append((j, check_radio.get())))
            radio_int.deselect()
            radio_int.grid(row=2 + j, column=2)

            radio_str = tk.Radiobutton(data_frame, text='String', variable=check_radio, value=2,
                                       command=str_int_lst.append((j, check_radio.get())))
            radio_str.deselect()
            radio_str.grid(row=2 + j, column=3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    program = Creation(root)
    program.grid()
    program.mainloop()
```

Comment: put the `check_radio = tk.StringVar()` inside the `for j in range(10):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reusing the same variable for every set of radiobuttons. Each set of radiobuttons needs its own variable. You need to create a new variable for each iteration of the loop.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
...
entry = list()
radio_vars = []
for j in range(10):
    ...
    check_radio = tk.StringVar()
    radio_vars.append(check_radio)
    ...
```